# To expand a function to power series

Tags: calculus, analysis

For $$ f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}\right) $$

1. Where is the convergence zone?
2. How to calculate the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)!} $?

Comment: Do you know any complex analysis?

Comment: Yes,but a little.

Comment: How little? Does "removable singularity" draw a blank, or elicit a "yes, of course"?

Comment: For (1) it is a matter of taste. Expand and differentiate term by term. The resulting series converges everywhere. Some people would exclude $0$, for in my opinion not useful reason.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer draw a blank...

Comment: Pity. Still, do you know that you can differentiate a power series term by term in its region of convergence?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yes~

Comment: Okay. Expand $e^x-1$ into a power series, divide by $x$, differentiate.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yes, I get it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is differentiable everywhere except $0$, which is a removable singularity and you can expand it to a holomorphic function on whole $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$).
Indeed, If you expand it as follows:

$\displaystyle \tilde{f}(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{e^z-1}{z}&z\neq0\\
0&z=0
\end{array}\right.$

Then $\tilde{f}$ is an entire function And it's Taylor series will be :

\begin{align*}
&\tilde{f}(x)=1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\cdots=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^i}{(i+1)!}\\
\Longrightarrow& \tilde{f}'(z)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{(i+1)!}z^{i-1} = \frac{xe^x-e^x+1}{x^2}
\end{align*}
Now it's remained to compute $f'(1)$.

Comment: Beautiful answer,but I'm not familiar with complex analysis..

Comment: @user152441: You don't have to be. All you have to be familiar with is the [Taylor series for the exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Characterizations), $e^x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: As @Lucian said, almost all i did here you can do in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Fardad Pouran,Lucian, Thank you!